# how do I dynamically generate multiple HTTP mock responses with VCR for Ruby/RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, yaml, erb, vcr

I'm hitting an API and for each request, there was a recorded request/response in the cassette YAML file. However, the only difference between the requests was the `id` in the query parameters.

How do I shrink my YAML file so that URLs are dynamically generated for each request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic ERB Cassettes](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/3-0-3/docs/cassettes/dynamic-erb-cassettes) with VCR, you just have to pass in the `:erb` option which can have a value of `true` or a hash containing the template variables to be passed to the cassette:

```rb
ids = [0, 1, 2, 3]
VCR.use_cassette('dynamic_generated_requests', :erb => { :ids => ids }) do
  # Make HTTP Requests
end
```

### YAML File with ERB

And your YAML file would look like this:

```yaml
---
http_interactions:
<% ids.each do |id| %>
- request:
    method: post
    uri: https://api.example.com/path/to/rest_api/<%= id %>/method
    body:
      encoding: UTF-8
    headers:
      content-type:
      - application/json
  response:
    status:
      code: 200
      message: OK
    headers:
      cache-control:
      - no-cache, no-store
      content-type:
      - application/json
      connection:
      - Close
    body:
      encoding: UTF-8
      string: '{"status_code": <%= id %>}'
    http_version: '1.1'
  recorded_at: Tue, 15 Jan 2019 16:14:14 GMT
<% end %>
recorded_with: VCR 3.0.0
```

*Note: the `.yml` file extension is still used because VCR handles the ERB processing through the `:erb` option.*

## Debugging: `raw_cassette_bytes`

If you want to debug this and make sure the YAML file looks good, you can print out the rendered YAML file with the [raw_cassette_bytes](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/blob/v3.0.0/lib/vcr/cassette.rb#L231-L233) method:

```rb
puts VCR.current_cassette.send(:raw_cassette_bytes)
```

Use that within the VCR.use_cassette block:

```rb
VCR.use_cassette('dynamic_generated_requests', :erb => { :ids => ids }) do
  puts VCR.current_cassette.send(:raw_cassette_bytes)
  # Make HTTP Requests
end
```